# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client (multiple data entries)

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

So I was trying to INSERT then UPDATE data, database was successfully updating based on the intended queries and was able to receive the response to the client but getting the error above on the server, not sure how to debug it, I've tried to look with the previous related questions with no luck.

```
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
router.post('/createprovision', urlencodedParser,(req, res) => {
    let serials = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++){
        serials.push(req.body[i][1]);
    }  

    let sql = 'INSERT INTO provision (employee_id, serial_no, provision_date) VALUES ?';
    connection.query(sql, [req.body],(err, results) => {
        for(let i = 0; i < serials.length; i++){
            let sql2 = `UPDATE inventory SET ? WHERE serial_no = '${serials[i]}'`;
            connection.query(sql2, [{status: "assigned"}],(err, results) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                return res.send("provision success!");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

ERR_MSG :

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
>   to the client (multiple data entries)

Comment: Usually you can only send the headers once, and it has to happen with or before the first "output", because the browser needs to know what kind of data it is receiving. I am not so experienced with Nodejs, but perhaps you're accidentally sending something (an error?) to the browser before you're actually sending headers? My advice would be to check exactly what is sent to the browser (given that you are sending to a browser, but any client would do) and when.

Answer (score 1):

You've put your `return res.send("provision success!");` inside a for-loop which means you send a response to the client in your first iteration, then you are attempting to send response again but the headers were already sent. Place it at the end of your function, sending the response only after your process all `serials`.

Comment: that actually made sense, didn't mentally noticed it inside the loop. Thanks man!